# Set child game object as active

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have a gameobject that is inactive at the start of the game. So, I put it inside a parent object that is active at the beginning of the game. The active at start parent object is `Scoreboard` it's **inactive** child is called `Win`.
I think this because I'm getting this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What I'm doing right now that isn't working is assigning values to a `scoreboard` and `win` variable at start like so: (before the start method)

```
GameObject win;
GameObject scoreboard;
```

In `Start()`:

```
scoreboard = GameObject.Find("Scoreboard");
win = GameObject.Find("/Scoreboard/Win");
```

Note: I feel like my problem is assigning `win` an inactive object, but I could be wrong.

If that's not it I made a method called Reset:

```
void Reset()
{
    WorldController.IsRunning = false;
    win.SetActive(true);
}
```

`WorldController.cs` handles the speed of the world and other things as my game is a runner. Problem isn't here this script has worked fine.

I'm calling the reset method inside of `OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)`
right here:

```
 if (collision.collider.tag == "Obstacles")
    {
        hits++;
        lives--;
        L4txt.text = "Lives: " + lives;
        if (hits == 3)
        {
            Reset();
        }

    }
```

`hits` and `lives`are score values(int) that aren't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Note: I feel like my problem is assigning win an inactive object, but I could be wrong."

EXACTLY!

it won't find inactive obects

SOLUTION!

*use a public variable -- drag it in the inspector*

Comment: will I need to use Find still in start?

Comment: no, do not use Find.  just use the public and "drag" !